# remove row when element in table found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the row where the text is not found, when checkbox unchecked . If checkbox checked, then the table needs to return to its original state . What can you recommend?

```
function keySearch() {
        $('#search').keyup(function (e) {
            var search = $(this).val();
            $('td').removeClass('found');
            $('td').each(function (index, element) {
                if ($(element).html() == search) {
                    $(element).addClass('found');
                }
                if (!$('#checkbox').prop('checked', true)) {
                    $(element).parent().hide();
                }
                else
                {
                  $(element).parent().show();//how replace remove row?
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to remove a row, or just hide it?

Comment: just hide, y are right

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using JavaScript to show and hide the rows, you could use it to add or remove a `.checked` CSS class on the parent table. Then set up the `.found` class so that it only hides the rows if the `.checked` class is present. **You'll need to add the `.found` class to the rows instead of the cells for this to work**. Just add `.parent()` before `.addClass('found')` in your code. Also, get rid of the code below your first `if` statement.

Here's what the CSS would look like:

```
table.checked > * > tr.found {
  display: none;
}
```

Some additional code will be needed to make the checkbox work. Here's how to do it with plain ol' JavaScript (sorry, I don't use jQuery much):

```
document.querySelector('#checkbox').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.checked)
    document.querySelector('#table').classList.add('checked');
  else
    document.querySelector('#table').classList.remove('checked');
});
```

(This assumes that your table has an id of 'table').